# To Connect to MYSQL - How to access database array in setting.php

Tags: 7, configuration

I need to connect to my database in php file in drupal 7. Each time I move from local server to development server, I have to change my db and host. I have seen `setting.php` file which have array of database.

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'my_db',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

How do I aceess this database array in drupal 7 to use it connecting to database

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','my_db');
```

Thanks for Help

Comment: First of all it's a bad practice to connect to Mysql Using mysqli_connect inside drupal that too in php file... You might need to explain why you are using .php file inside and what you trying to achieve..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access the Drupal database from a standalone script.

Firstly, consider if you can put the PHP code in a Drupal module instead.
Secondly, consider bootstrapping Drupal in your PHP script

```
/**
 * Root directory of Drupal installation.
 */
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/var/www/drupal');

// Bootstrap to database level for db api
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE);
```

You can then use the [Drupal database API](https://drupal.org/developing/api/database) to query content from the Drupal database.

Thirdly, if connecting to a different database is required, consider defining the other database in settings.php and switching to a target database using [`db_set_active`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_set_active/7)

```
// Settings.php
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'drupal7',
  'username' => 'drupal_user',
  'password' => 'drupal_password',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'prefix' => '',
);

$databases['other_database']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'other_database',
  'username' => 'other_database_user',
  'password' => 'other_database_password',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'prefix' => '',
);
```

Then you can switch between databases with `db_set_active`

```
// Query other database
db_set_active('other_database');
// $query = db_select('my_table'); // e.g
// Return to default database
db_set_active();
```

Comment: while switching between database, Do I have to come back to db_set_active()--> to default database each time ?

Comment: Drupal will switch back to the default db at the end of the page execution, use db_set_active() or db_set_active('default') to switch it back manually.

Comment: Thanks I learnt something !!! thank you so much for answering :)

Comment: This don't answer the question. Is a good answer, but is not what OP is asking.